# My component child doesn't loaded by parent

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm searching a solution for my problem : I want to load my component AddArticle.vue on Home.vue with httpVueLoader, I have tried many times with   `components: {"AddArticle" : window.httpVueLoader('./components/AddArticle.vue')}`, or  `components: {"AddArticle" : httpVueLoader('./components/AddArticle.vue')},` but my problem is always here.... My component "AddArticle.vue" has not be displayed on my component "Home.vue", why ?

Thanks you in advance everyone

All my component and sources:

**Home.vue**

```
<template>

  <div>
    <AddArticle/>
    <article v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">
      <div class="article-img">
        <div :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + article.image + ')' }">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="article-content" v-if="editingArticle.id !== article.id">
        <div class="article-title">
          <h2>{{ article.name }} - {{ article.price }}€</h2>
          <div>
          <button @click="deleteArticle(article.id)">Supprimer</button>
          <button @click="editArticle(article)">Modifier</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="article-content" v-else>
        <div class="article-title">
          <h2><input type="text" v-model="editingArticle.name"> - <input type="number" v-model="editingArticle.price"></h2>
          <div>
            <button @click="sendEditArticle()">Valider</button>
            <button @click="abortEditArticle()">Annuler</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p><textarea v-model="editingArticle.description"></textarea></p>
        <input type="text" v-model="editingArticle.image" placeholder="Lien vers l'image">
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>


</template>

<script>

module.exports = {
  props: {
    articles: { type: Array, default: [] },
    panier: { type: Object }
  },
  components: {"AddArticle" : httpVueLoader('./components/AddArticle.vue')},

  data () {
    return {
      edit: 'test',
      editingArticle: {
        id: -1,
        name: '',
        description: '',
        image: '',
        price: 0
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addArticle () {
      alert("Piti")
    },
    deleteArticle (articleId) {
      this.$emit('delete-article', articleId)
    },
    editArticle (article) {
      this.editingArticle.id = article.id
      this.editingArticle.name = article.name
      this.editingArticle.description = article.description
      this.editingArticle.image = article.image
      this.editingArticle.price = article.price
    },
    sendEditArticle () {
      this.$emit('update-article', this.editingArticle)
      this.abortEditArticle()
    },
    abortEditArticle () {
      this.editingArticle = {
        id: -1,
        name: '',
        description: '',
        image: '',
        price: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
article {
  display: flex;
}

.article-img {
  flex: 1;
}

.article-img div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.article-content {
  flex: 3;
}

.article-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**AddArticle.vue**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="addArticle">
    <h2>Nouveau produit à ajouter</h2>

    <input type="text" v-model="newArticle.name" placeholder="Nom du produit" required/>
    <input type="number" v-model="newArticle.price" placeholder="Prix" required>
    <textarea  v-model="newArticle.description" required></textarea>
    <input type="text" v-model="newArticle.image" placeholder="Lien vers l'image">
    <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: {
    articles: { type: Array, default: [] },
    panier: { type: Object }
  },
  data () {
    return {
          newArticle: {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            image: '',
            price: 0
          },

    }
  },
  methods: {
    addArticle() {
      this.$emit('add-article')
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
  },}

</script>
```

**vue-application.js**

```
const Home = window.httpVueLoader('./components/Home.vue')
const Panier = window.httpVueLoader('./components/Panier.vue')
const AddArticle = window.httpVueLoader('./components/AddArticle.vue')

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/panier', component: Panier },
  { path: "/article", component: AddArticle},


]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

var app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    articles: [],
    panier: {
      createdAt: null,
      updatedAt: null,
      articles: []
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/articles')
    this.articles = res.data
    // const res2 = await axios.get('/api/panier')
    // this.panier = res2.data
  },
  methods: {
    async addArticle (article) {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/article', article)
      this.articles.push(res.data)
    },
    async updateArticle (newArticle) {
      await axios.put('/api/article/' + newArticle.id, newArticle)
      const article = this.articles.find(a => a.id === newArticle.id)
      article.name = newArticle.name
      article.description = newArticle.description
      article.image = newArticle.image
      article.price = newArticle.price
    },
    async deleteArticle (articleId) {
      await axios.delete('/api/article/' + articleId)
      const index = this.articles.findIndex(a => a.id === articleId)
      this.articles.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mon magasin en ligne 100% bons plans</title>
        <!-- Load Vue followed by Vue Router -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/http-vue-loader/src/httpVueLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
          <header>
            <h1>À la bonne franquette</h1>
            <nav>
              <router-link to='/'>Accueil</router-link>
              <router-link to='/panier'>Panier</router-link>
              <router-link to="/article"> AjoutArticle </router-link>
            </nav>
          </header>
          <main>
            <router-view
              :articles="articles"
              :panier="panier"
              @add-article="addArticle"
              @delete-article="deleteArticle"
              @update-article="updateArticle"
            ></router-view>
          </main>
        </div>
        <script src="/vue-application.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: the author of `httpVueLoader` announced in march 2021 that it is no longer supported  - the author suggests another one of his creations: [vue3-sfc-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader) - he claims it supports both vue2 and vue3 despite its name

Comment: Even it's no longer supported... It works on my Website, because my router link works, only the component added on Home doesn't work. Do you have an other idea to bypass that problème ?

Comment: what makes you say that? anyway, are there any errors in the browser developer tools console like I asked in the first comment you seem to have ignored?

Comment: I've Seen the console, so I've put : component : { 'add-article', window.httpVueLoader(path of my component) }and this Time, it worked and I put <add-article/> in my template, but it's weird... I have tested this before posting and doesn't work... Web programming is Always a mistery....

Comment: `Home.vue` and `AddArticle.vue` are in components, yet `Home.vue` tries to load `AddArticle` like `httpVueLoader('./components/AddArticle.vue')` ... that should not work

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. You won't see [solved] in titles on SO. You also shouldn't see tags.

Comment: in vue, you do `components: {"AddArticle" : httpVueLoader('path')},` but use `<add-article>` - it's spelled out in the documentation